# Change JPanel default graphics

Tags: java, swing, jpanel, graphics2d

when I have `JPanel`, it has it´s default Graphics which is passed to `paint(Graphics g)` and similiar function. Can I somehow switch that default `Graphics` for my own? From outside of the `JPanel class`? I am looking for something like `JPanel.setGraphics(Graphics g)`. Thank you.

Comment: Why would you want to do something like this? What is your purpose?

Comment: Becouse in my computer graphics class, we use Java as school default language of choice. We have support library written by programming teacher. I suggested to replace BufferedImage with Volatile image to speed things up... In order to do so, without having original source, only JAR file, and leaving the same interface intact, I need to replace its Graphics img, without ability to override paint method...

Comment: Even with just a Jar file, you should be able to extend whatever JPanel-derived object in the Jar file, override its paintComponent method and all your own graphics code in that method. The only way that I see this is not possible is if the jar classes are immutable with final classes and private paintComponent methods.

Comment: I know, but I worry that I ovverride something used by something eventually causing crash or some nasty exception :)

Comment: Fiddlesticks. So you'd rather try to do something as skanky as replace the Graphics object? Come on, put on your big-boy pants and override paintComponent. Be sure to call the super's method first inside of your override.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, but you may override its `paintComponent` method, cast the `Graphics` object passed as argument to `Graphics2D`, and draw whatever you want on it.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know, the only way to control which Graphics object is passed around is to enable the debug graphics option. This is done by calling `JComponent.setDebugGraphicsOptions(int)`, which will replace the original Graphics object by an instance of `javax.swing.DebugGraphics`.

The instanciation of `DebugGraphics` is hardcoded in the method `getGraphics` of class `JComponent`, so I see no way to use your own implementation here (other than using the instrumentation of the JVM to rewrite the code, as mock libraries do).